# Groovy equivalent of Java 8 :: (double colon) operator

Tags: groovy, java-8, method-reference

What would the equivalent to Java 8 :: ([double colon operator](http://www.baeldung.com/java-8-double-colon-operator)) in Groovy?

I'm trying to translate this example in groovy https://github.com/bytefish/PgBulkInsert

But the mapping part doesn't work the same way as Java 8:

```
public PersonBulkInserter() {
    super("sample", "unit_test");

    mapString("first_name", Person::getFirstName);
    mapString("last_name", Person::getLastName);
    mapDate("birth_date", Person::getBirthDate);
}
```

Comment: Seems the Groovy method pointer operator `.&` is close but expects an instance of the declaring class.

Comment: Indeed, I would need a "Functional Interface" for a Groovy Class. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html

Comment: It's hard to tell without seeing the code for your `mapString()` and `mapDate()` methods, but maybe something like this would work: `mapString("first_name", { it.firstName } as Function)`. It's not as efficient as the function-pointer-to-lambda-to-Functional-interface notation in java 8, but I think it will work out the same.

Comment: @BalRog Thanks a lot, it works ;) You should submit an answer. I was expecting Groovy to have a way to leverage the Lambda Functional Interfaces. Btw the code is available on https://github.com/bytefish/PgBulkInsert/blob/master/PgBulkInsert/src/main/java/de/bytefish/pgbulkinsert/PgBulkInsert.java#L168

Comment: I have done as you asked

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Groovy doesn't really have instance-divorced instance-method references (EDIT: *Yet*. See Wavyx's comment on this answer.), so instead you have to fake it with closures. When using instance-method reference syntax in Java 8, you are really setting up the equivalent of a lambda that expects the invoking instance as its first (in this case, only) argument.

Thus, to get the same effect in Groovy we have to create a closure that uses the default `it` argument as the invoking instance. Like this:

```
PersonBulkInserter() {
    super("sample", "unit_test")

    mapString("first_name", { it.firstName } as Function)
    mapString("last_name", { it.lastName } as Function)
    mapDate("birth_date", { it.birthDate } as Function)
}
```

Notice the use of Groovy property notation here, and that it is necessary to cast the `Closure` to the `@FunctionalInterface` type expected by the `mapString()` or `mapDate()` method.

Comment: Java 8 :: (double colon) will be added in 2017 https://twitter.com/glaforge/status/814890698369593348

Comment: Did this get released?

Comment: No idea. You could try tweeting "glaforge" for an update (See link in Wavyx's comment). I hear he's pretty responsive.

Comment: As of now (2.6.0-alpha-2) not working.  But does anyone know whether this will be added to Groovy 2 or Groovy 3, currently described as "bleeding edge" (http://groovy-lang.org/download.html)?

Answer (score 6):

As of Groovy 3 (beta), groovy now has [support](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#_method_references) for java 8 colon syntax ([and more](http://groovy-lang.org/releasenotes/groovy-3.0.html#releasenotes)).

So the example you have will work exactly the same in groovy.