# How to reference a method on the object itself

Tags: java, groovy, java-8, method-reference

In java I can write

```
Arrays.asList("test  ").stream().map(String::trim);
```

If I try this in groovy

```
Arrays.asList("test  ").stream().map(String.&trim)
```

I get

```
    Caught: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: java.lang.String.trim() is applicable for argument types: (String) values: [test  ]
Possible solutions: trim(), wait(), grep(), wait(long), split(java.lang.String), print(java.io.PrintWriter)
```

---

What is the correct syntax or do I have to resort to

```
    Arrays.asList("test  ").stream().map({ x -> x.trim() })
```

?

Comment: maybe this can help you [Groovy equivalent of Java 8 :: (double colon) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41398751/groovy-equivalent-of-java-8-double-colon-operator)

Answer (score 0):

you can use `.map { it.trim() }` too, but otherwise, groovy does not have method reference working like java one